# How to add new cell by column name in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Is it possible to add new cell base on column name? How can I possibly do this?

As of now here is my code

```
foreach (var c in br)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = c.AccountCode });
            foreach (var r in c.TBal)
            {
                //add new cell base on c.AccountCode
            }
        }
```

My br has this data

[image]

Any ideas? thanks :)

What I want to happen is that AccountCode should be column and `TBal balance` should its data under it and so on..

Comment: there is no code of yours, just two for-each loops. Have you tried anything on your own? And what do you exactly mean by saying 'cell base'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying to guess here what you want.
You could probably add the `Name` property for the column name aside from `HeaderText` property  and use that column name identity to populate the cells.

```
{ HeaderText = c.AccountCode, Name = "colAccountCode" }
```

So, let's just say you are using the name `colAccountCode` as your column name for this new column. So, you will have this code that would probably look like this;

```
 foreach (var c in br)
 {
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = c.AccountCode, Name = "colAccountCode" });
    int rows = dataGridView1.Rows.Count, rowCtr = 0;
    if (rows>0) // Make sure there are rows in DataGridView
       { 
         foreach (var r in c.TBal)
         {
            if (rowCtr < rows) // Make sure that rowCtr is less than Total Rows since index always starts with zero
               {
                 dataGridView1.Rows[rowCtr++].Cells["colAccountCode"].Value = r;
               }
         }
       }
    }
```